# Copy Password From DialogBox Message Using Imacros

Tags: javascript, imacros

Is there any way to copy password from dialogbox message using imacros or greacemonkey and paste it to another page?
[Please check the image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRLAY.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

See how it can be solved with the JavaScript Scripting Interface in 'iMacros' for Firefox:

```
// just an imitation of your page js-dialog with one second delay
window.location.href = 'javascript:{window.setTimeout("window.location.href=\'javascript:{alert(\\"Bla bla bla ... DDA9B7 ... bla bla bla\\");}\'", 1000); undefined;}';

// macro that waits for the dialog
var ret = iimPlayCode("WAIT SECONDS=1.5");
// extract dialog text
if (ret < 0) 
    var otp = iimGetErrorText();
// extract otp
otp = otp.match(/\b[A-Z0-9]{6}\b/);
// pass it to another macro or display as done below
iimDisplay(otp);
```