# Extract Text from pop up windows by imacros and paste it on field

Tags: javascript, imacros

I want to copy and paste text from popup window which is open on same tab by macros. i did not get proper answer on my previous post. i have captured the image

[Here is an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPwcT.jpg) showing the text that I need to copy.

This is the code that I am using to paste.

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:OnlineForm ATTR=ID:passport_no CONTENT={{!VAR2}}
```

Comment: Check out [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35954703/copy-password-from-dialogbox-message-using-imacros).

Comment: please addon your skype gs_sharwar i am in great trouble please help me